# low latency using lists

Tags: java, collections

Can someone help me understand the following statement that I read in relation to low latency programming:

Try to minimize number of Objects you have. For example, prefer array-based structures like ArrayList/ArrayDeque to pointer based structures like LinkedList.

I am aware that an arraylist may perform better in a fragmented heap;but never realized it involves less objects.
On the contrary,I was aware that arraylist actually necessitates creation of additional objects than actually needed .

Comment: Can you please tell us where you've read that?

Comment: A Node in a LinkedList typically uses 24-32 bytes of memory, per element. An ArrayList typically uses 4-8 bytes per element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `LinkedList` uses a `Node` object to wrap each element you add to it. So if you add 10 objects to the `LinkedList`, you actually need another 10 objects to hold them.

Although an `ArrayList` will regenerate its backing array from time to time based on additions and removals, it only needs the one backing array object to hold all the objects you add to it.

Garbage collection and object creation isn't always negligible.

Comment: More than just adding a ```Node```, those nodes aren't necessarily in contiguous memory, so ```iterator.next()``` might be a cache miss.